# Unable to get @Service wired correctly with Spring Data JPA, No qualifying bean found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am having a problem trying to setup a `@Service`, `ArchiveService` in a library lets call it `App1`, which is used by my second application, `App2`.

I have been able to successfully setup `@Repository`s from `App1` which are used via `@Autowired` in `App2` without issues.

Now I am trying to setup `ArchiveService` a `@Service` which will have multiple `@Autowired` archive `@Repositories`.

The problem happens when I try to reference the `ArchiveService` form within the `HomeController` of `App2` I am running into a

```
Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'archiveService': No qualifying bean of type [com.miw.mcb.server.service.ArchiveService] found for dependency [com.miw.mcb.server.service.ArchiveService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

This seems odd that it says

```
No qualifying bean of type [app1.server.service.ArchiveService] found for dependency [app1.server.service.ArchiveService]
```

**Question**

What is wrong with my setup of the `@Service`, `ArchiveService`, for `HomeController` which has no problem finding the `@Repository`'s for the various repositories used by `HomeController`.

**UPDATE**

I added the component scan of the service package to App2.

```
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.miw.mcb.server.service.archived")
```

I am going to have to do some reading to see if this is doing what I intend it to do.  Is there another way for the `@Service`'s to be loaded?  I know the using @EnableJpaRepositories works for the repositories.

Thank you

Here is a breakdown of the classes and spring configuration.

**APPLICATION 1 classes which are part of a dependent library for App2**

**TestRunRepository**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface TestRunRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<TestRun, Long> {
}
```

**ArchivedTestRunRepository**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface ArchivedTestRunRepository extends CrudRepository<ArchivedTestRun, Long> {

}
....  (all of the archive repositories are the same)
```

**ArchiveService**

```
@Service
public class ArchiveService {


    // setup Archive repositories 
    @Autowired
    private ArchivedTestRunRepository archivedTestRunRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ArchivedTestSuiteRepository archivedTestSuiteRepository;
```

**APPLICATION 2**

**HomeController**

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {


    @Autowired
    private TestRunRepository testRunRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ArchiveService archiveService;
    .......

}
```

**AppConfig for App2**

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan({"xxx.app1.model", "xxx.app1.model.archived"})
@EnableJpaRepositories({ "xxx.app1.dao.repository", "xxx.app1.dao.repository.archived", "xxx.app1.service" })
@SpringBootApplication
public class App2 {
    ...
}
```

On a side note I'm not sure if I actually need to list both "xxx.app1.dao.repository", "xxx.app1.dao.repository.archived" for `@EnableJpaRepositories` or if by defining the parent `package` it will pull in the `subpackage`.

**Stacktrace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'archiveService': No qualifying bean of type [app1.server.service.ArchiveService] found for dependency [app1.server.service.ArchiveService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [app1.server.service.ArchiveService] found for dependency [app1.server.service.ArchiveService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
  at app2.adbservice.Main.main(Main.java:20)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
  at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [app1.server.service.ArchiveService] found for dependency [app1.server.service.ArchiveService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1057)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
  ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Comment: How are the two applications related? Why are there even two applications to begin with?

Comment: @Andreas       The second application is a rest based application.  The applications sit on different servers but communicate to the same database.  The first application defines the model, repositories etc.

Comment: So if class `ArchiveService` sits in Application 1 on Server 1, how did you expect Spring to assign it to class `HomeController` in Application 2 on Server 2? They are not in the same JVM. They are not even on the same server!!! Think about it. How can an object reference be *physically* shared when they are not in the same JVM? Answer: It can't.

Comment: @Andreas Application 1 is packaged as a dependency for Application 2 in its build process to have access to the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to replace `@SpringBootApplication` annotation in App2 with `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"app1.server.service"})`. I think the application only scan Entity and Repository beans, because of current configuration.

Using `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"app1"})` might be even more useful, since it will scan not only services package but whole app1 package.

Comment: I moved "ArchiveService" into its own package since it was causing a problem with the component scan. Is this the only way to load the Service?  I added the update above.

Comment: dnz, be aware that [App1 and App2 are running on different servers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605088/unable-to-get-service-wired-correctly-with-spring-data-jpa-no-qualifying-bean?noredirect=1#comment66518958_39605088). `ArchiveService` is not even present in App2, where `HomeController` is. OP is confused about what auto-wiring can do, and think it'll magically auto-wire between servers. *<baffled>*

Comment: Oh thanks @Andreas I didn't realise that. Then it is impossible to refer it from one to another. And ALM may I ask why are you deploying applications on different servers and why do you have another app for model/repository definitions instead of just having them under another package?

Comment: @dnzprmksz     It is not impossible to reference it, application 2 has a dependency on application 1 when it is built with maven.   It was setup to be different applications so that app 2 can be deployed on different servers and have the main server be app 1 where the model/repository and ui sit.

Comment: @ALM The Maven dependency means that *compilation* works, but since the dependency is missing at *runtime*, you get the Spring equivalency of a [`NoClassDefFoundError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html). Because, you know, **the class is not there**, or as the javadoc says: *The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.*

Comment: @Andreas       Adding the  ComponentScan to pickup the service for App2 seems to work when run by the application.  Would this not be the same as using any other type of library?  It is working for access to the Repository from App2.  Maybe I am not using autowired for this as it is originally intended.

Comment: @ALM If you include the code of App1 with the code of App2, then the App1 code is running on Server2, not Server1. It may *also* run on Server1, but when App2 code invokes the `ArchiveService`, it'll be running code on Server2. It will not be delegating the call over to Server1, so Server1 is besides the point. You confused the issue by saying that App1 code was only running on Server1.

Comment: @Andreas       Yes I can see how that would have been confusing at this point.  I will rewrite the question.  What is the correct way for App2 to read the service though?  Should it be done with a ComponentScan or is there another way specific for Services?  Thank you